# timed java loop

Tags: java, android, loops, time

I am new android and I would appreciate some help. I have this code:

```
        dateatm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        timeatm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMM/dd");
        SimpleDateFormat värk = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
        String timeNow = värk.format(currentDate.getTime());
        dateatm.setText(dateNow);
        timeatm.setText(timeNow);
```

As you can see, I am getting date and time out of it. What I want tho is that there would be 1 second loop, so after every 1 second, it will update date and time again and again to the newer one to get basically clock. I am pretty newcomer so all help is appreciated how to get this done. If you would bring exact examples I would appreciate as it makes it more easier to understand, not just "Oh, use that and that and that. Thank you!".

Thanks for your help and time,
Elven :)

---

Error for answer 1:

```
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:642)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:668)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5507)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2724)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at viimane.voimalus.MainStuff$1.run(MainStuff.java:55)
08-10 18:55:41.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(886):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved this issue in my project (executing code at specific interval) :)

Edited to reflect updated answer:

```
protected static final int REFRESH = 0;
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask refresher;

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case REFRESH:
            /* your code here */
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

// Initialization code in onCreate or similar:

```
timer = new Timer();    
refresher = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        ActivityMain.this.sendEmptyMessage(REFRESH);
    };
};
// first event immediately,  following after 1 seconds each
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresher, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: hmm, it gives me error after 1 second. I'll put error into opening post. Do you know what might be cause?

Comment: You have to update UI from UI thread. TaskTimer's code appears to in different. We have to send signal from TaskTimer to Activity that it's time to refresh data. `ActivityMain.this.sendEmptyMessage(REFRESH);` sends message, `Handler` receives. Then you check what message you received and if it is `REFRESH` - execute code you wrote in your question.

Comment: But where goes what exactly? Do I change ActivityMain to that class on what it is? Cuz it gives me error: It cannot be resolved to type :/

Comment: It's code taken from my project, where ActivityMain is class of activity which does the updates.