# How to make a timer continuously running until closed by user?

Tags: android, timer

I have made a countdown timer where I set the time that I want and it counts down this runs in a loop increasing each round once timer hits 0. I have manage to get this working but once I open other apps that force the program to close due and I return to the timer it has lost it current information require me to start from the start.

How would I go about preventing the app from closing and keeping it to continuously run, until the user decides to close the program.

Also I a new to Android coding first program I have made for it. So very new to the whole system.

Comment: search other similar threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015994/timed-java-loop

Comment: [May this help you](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/01/timer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the timers method:

```
 Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourtimertask, yourdelay, yourinterval);
```

**Ths method will execute the code inside your TimerTask everytime the interval time passes.**

Here is a simple example of a Timer inside an Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    MyTimerTask yourTask = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer t = new Timer();

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourTask, 0, 10000);  // 10 sec interval      
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          // do whatever you want in here
      }
}
```

I created my own TimerTask where I can do stuff inside its run method. In the onCreate() method, I start the timer and execute the code inside the Tasks run() method every 10 seconds.

Furthermore, you should also have a look at the Android **AlarmManager** and **PendingIntents**.

Read more about that in this nice tutorial:

> http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html

Comment: I have already used the Timer. My timer works 100% fine. The problem is that when it is running in background (multiple apps running at the same time) This app seems to close require me to reset my timer and lose the counted rounds.

Comment: Furthermore, you should also have a look at the Android AlarmManager and PendingIntents. Please read my full answer :)